# How to add name field in newsletter form Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter

I want to add new filed in newsletter form like name, pin code, phone number, and Date of Birth field so please suggest or help me.

Comment: I need to Add these field in newsletter form at front and after submit  should be show in admin area.

Answer (score 1):

I found a good module that adds first name, last name, and many other fields that's configurable in admin. Works very good here:

[Newsletter Extended](https://github.com/aligent/newsletter-extended)

I use Magento ver. 1.9.2.2